# Показывает иероглифы, как решить данную проблему

Tags: c#

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string fn = (string)e.Node.Tag;
    if (File.Exists(fn))
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(fn, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```

Материал теста сохранен как Ворд

[image: Скриншот окна программы]

При использование rtf документа у меня текст не распознаёт кириллицу

Comment: Вы пытаетесь загрузить текст как чистый текст (PlainText), а там похоже вордовский документ. Надо как то это дело согласовать.

Comment: @KoVadim, нужно высчитывать вордовский документ

Comment: richTextBox не поддерживает вордовский документ. Вы можете переконвертировать в RTF.

Comment: если немного закрыть глаза и сохранить вордовский документ в rtf, и убрать PlainText, то все может получится

Comment: WINAPI +rich вроде поддерживает вордовский документ в урезаном виде, на  7-ке+ думаю, но в c# почему-то не добавили поддержку

Comment: Решить можно двумя способами, либо использовать нормальный RTF документ с richTextBox, либо используйте контрол, который умеет работать с docx.